# SQL command execution sequence in Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am displaying a list of items on my view. My controller class executes a sql in order to get the list. Also I am updating some values in table once the list if fetched. The problem is the values are being set before the select statement. Below is the controller code:

```
@orders = List.select("itemname,tableno,quantity,itmstatus").where(:tableno => "01")
List.where(:tableno => "01").update_all(:ordstatus => 'displayed',:itmstatus => 'displayed')
```

My view displays different fields retrieved in `@orders`. Now based on itemstatus value I need to set the text color code in my view. So once my select statement is executed, I set the itmstatus value to some other value. But in my view the @orders has the updated value (which I am doing after select). I checked on server side and the select statement is executed after the update statement which I think might be the case for having updated value in @orders. Is there any way through which I can have the update statement execute after select. I tried below and couple of other options but no luck.

```
if @orders
 @orders = List.select("itemname,tableno,quantity,itmstatus").where(:tableno => "01")
 List.where(:tableno => "01").update_all(:ordstatus => 'displayed',:itmstatus => 'displayed')
end
```

Please advise. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The thing is that the code `@orders = List.select("itemname,tableno,quantity,itmstatus").where(:tableno => "01")` is *lazily evaluated* when the view enumerates the `@orders` instance variable. That is, it's an `ActiveRecord::Relation` that only really gets evaluated (the SQL executed) at the time the view is rendered.

One way to prevent this—to fully execute the query and retrieve all the rows before the update statement later on is to call `to_a` on the `ActiveRecord::Relation`.

```
@orders = List.select(...).where(...).to_a
```

One thing to look out for is if you're using Kaminari for pagination then the regular Kaminari pagination extensions won't work—you'll have to use `Kaminari::paginate_array`.

Another thing to consider is if your query can potentially return a large number of records. By calling `to_a` you're telling ActiveRecord to retrieve all those records into memory all at once, which can degrade performance.

Note that, in Rails 3 it's also possible to use the `.all` method (as in, `List.select().where().all`) to execute and evaluate the query. However, in Rails 4, `Model.all` is now equivalent to `Model.scoped` and is lazily evaluated, hence, `.to_a`

---

Alternatively, you might want to look at the [`ActiveRecord::Relation#load`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Relation.html#method-i-load) method:

> Causes the records to be loaded from the database if they have not been loaded already. 
>   You can use this if for some reason you need to explicitly load some records before 
>   actually using them. The return value is the relation itself, not the records.

Admittedly, I've never actually used that but it might be more appropriate in this case.

Comment: Thanks a lot. .to_a worked. My query will have max 10 rows so performance wise its not an issue. Thanks again for detailed explanation. This helps a lot.